# pooled connection + validation query + SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS

Tags: spring, jdbc, database-connection, apache-commons-dbcp, sql-calc-found-rows

I have the problem that my web application running on tomcat often drops the following exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Connection already closed
```

So I want to validate the connection before getting it from the pool by the following config:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />        
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/database" />
    <property name="username" value="user" />
    <property name="password" value="pass" />
    <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1"/>
    <property name="testOnReturn" value="false"/>
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"/>
    <property name="testWhileIdle" value="false"/>
    <property name="maxActive" value="30" />
    <property name="maxIdle" value="15" />
    <property name="minIdle" value="5"/>
    <property name="poolPreparedStatements" value="true"/>
    <property name="connectionProperties"
        value="useUnicode=true;characterEncoding=UTF-8;profileSQL=true;logger=custom.MysqlLogger;" />
</bean>
```

when sending the following 2 queries with spring jdbcTemplate:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS col1, col2, col3 AS foo FROM table HAVING foo = 'bar' LIMIT 0, 10;
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

The "SELECT FOUND_ROWS()" query always returns 1 because the validation query is executed in between ("SELECT 1").

Does someone know a way to solve this problem without using COUNT in a second query???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are both your queries in the same transaction?

Comment: The above configuration in combination with using spring transactions solved my problem! P.S.: sorry for the late accepting ;)